# How to get the particular data set from curl response

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I'm trying to get the rcmDriverAgesInfo data from this

```
curl 'https://apis.rentalcarmanager.com/booking/v3.1/API_KEY/step2/0/5/17_11_2021/11_00/5/23_11_2021/11_00/2/0/-/-?apikey=API_KEY' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0' -H 'Accept: image/webp,*/*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=dksko0e9vkcuggi7lk7o94eaq1' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'TE: Trailers'
```

And  This is my code

```
<?
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://apis.rentalcarmanager.com/booking/v3.1/API_KEY=/step2/0/5/25_10_2021/11_00/5/30_10_2021/11_00/2/0/-/-?apikey=API_KEY=",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30000,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              // Set Here Your Requesred Headers
              'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
              'Accept: image/webp,*/*',
              'Content-Type: application/json',
              'charset=UTF-8',
              'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
              'Connection: keep-alive',
              'Cookie: PHPSESSID=dksko0e9vkcuggi7lk7o94eaq1',
              'Pragma: no-cache',
              'Cache-Control: no-cache',
            ),
        )
    );

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r($response,1);
```

This is curl output:

```
rcmLocationInfo = [{"id":"13","location":"ADELAIDE - 192 ONKAPARINGA VALLEY RD, WOODSIDE","webdefault":"False","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"2","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"16:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"0417 816 649","email":"woodside@deluxecamper.com.au","minbookingday":"0"},{"id":"4","location":"AIRLIE BEACH - 1678 SHUTE HARBOUR RD","webdefault":"False","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"0","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"16:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"0749483415","email":"tropicaccounts@whitsunday.net.au","minbookingday":"0"},{"id":"2","location":"BRISBANE - 40 FRENCH STREET EAGLE FARM","webdefault":"False","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"0","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"16:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"07 5575 5400","email":"info@fivestarcarrentals.com.au","minbookingday":"0"},{"id":"1","location":"CAIRNS - 440 SHERIDAN STREET CAIRNS","webdefault":"True","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"0","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"16:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"+6140813100","email":"sales@campermanaustralia.com","minbookingday":"0"},{"id":"12","location":"GOLDCOAST - 2/11 Northview St,Mermaid Wt","webdefault":"False","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"0","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"16:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"(07) 5572 0600","email":"enquiries@surfersrentacar.com.au","minbookingday":"0"},{"id":"6","location":"MELB - 273 Elizabeth Street Coburg","webdefault":"False","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"0","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"16:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"0393542945","email":"jpantonmotors@bigpond.com","minbookingday":"0"},{"id":"5","location":"SYDNEY - 23-25 ERSKINE RD CARINGBAH","webdefault":"False","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"0","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"14:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"02 9540 5066","email":"sales@getacarrentals.com","minbookingday":"0"},{"id":"3","location":"TOWNSVILLE - 167 Mount Low Parkway, MOUNT LOW, QLD","webdefault":"False","pickupavailable":"True","dropoffavailable":"True","flightnoreqd":"False","noticerequired":"0","daysquotevalid":"7","officeopeningtime":"09:00","officeclosingtime":"16:00","afterhourbooking":"True","unattendeddropoffs":"True","minimunage":"18","afterhourfeeid":"309","unattendeddropofffeesid":"0","phone":"0407191437","email":"sales@campermanaustralia.com","minbookingday":"0"}];
rcmOfficeTimes = [{"locid":"1","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"23:55","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"1","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"1","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"1","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"1","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"1","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"1","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"2","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"23:55","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"2","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"2","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"2","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"2","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"2","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"2","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"08:30","closingtime":"11:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:25","pmstart":"11:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"3","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"23:55","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"3","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"3","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"3","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"3","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"3","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"3","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"12:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"12:00","pmend":"15:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"15:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"4","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"23:55","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"4","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"4","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"4","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"4","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"4","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"4","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"08:30","closingtime":"11:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:25","pmstart":"11:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"5","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"12:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"5","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"5","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"5","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"5","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"19:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"19:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"5","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"5","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"12:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"12:00","pmend":"15:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"15:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"6","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"23:55","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"6","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"18:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"18:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"6","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"18:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"18:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"6","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"18:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"18:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"6","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"18:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"18:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"6","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"18:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"18:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"6","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"12:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"00:00","pmstart":"12:00","pmend":"15:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"15:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"12","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"23:55","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"12","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"12","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"12","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"12","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"12","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"12","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"08:30","closingtime":"11:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:25","pmstart":"11:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"13","wd":"1","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"00:00","closingtime":"00:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"23:55","pmstart":"00:00","pmend":"00:00","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"00:00","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"13","wd":"2","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"13","wd":"3","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"13","wd":"4","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"13","wd":"5","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"13","wd":"6","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"09:00","closingtime":"16:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:55","pmstart":"16:00","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"},{"locid":"13","wd":"7","afterhour":"True","unattended":"True","openingtime":"08:30","closingtime":"11:00","amstart":"00:00","amend":"08:25","pmstart":"11:05","pmend":"23:55","startpickup":"00:00","endpickup":"23:55","startdropoff":"00:00","enddropoff":"24:00"}];
rcmCategoryTypeInfo = [{"id":"6","categorytype":"CamperVan","ordering":"c","rentingtype":"True","raimage":"","rate12hour":"True","ratepernight":""}];
rcmDriverAgesInfo = [{"id":"10","driverage":"18","defaultage":"False"},{"id":"2","driverage":"19","defaultage":"False"},{"id":"3","driverage":"20","defaultage":"False"},{"id":"4","driverage":"21+","defaultage":"False"}];
rcmLocationFees = [{"cattypeid":"6","loctypeid":"1","loctype":"pickup","locationid":"5","currencyname":"","currencysymbol":"$","locdate":"25 Oct 2021","loctime":"11:00","dwname":"Monday","days4minbookingdaycheck":"6","location":"SYDNEY - 23-25 ERSKINE RD CARINGBAH","locdateloctime":"11-Oct-2021","tstavailable":"1","ierrorcode":"0","availablemsg":"","iafterhourpickup":"0","iafterhourdropoff":"0","tstminbookingday":"0","flightnoreqd":"False"},{"cattypeid":"6","loctypeid":"2","loctype":"dropoff","locationid":"5","currencyname":"","currencysymbol":"$","locdate":"30 Oct 2021","loctime":"11:00","dwname":"Saturday","days4minbookingdaycheck":"6","location":"SYDNEY - 23-25 ERSKINE RD CARINGBAH","locdateloctime":"11-Oct-2021","tstavailable":"1","ierrorcode":"0","availablemsg":"","iafterhourpickup":"0","iafterhourdropoff":"0","tstminbookingday":"0","flightnoreqd":"False"}];
rcmAvailableCarDetails = [];
rcmMandatoryFees = [{"cattypeid":"6","column1":"MandatoryFees","id":"414","locationid":"5","vehiclesizeid":"2","numofdays":"6","qty":"1","fees":"70.0000","name":"Administration Fee","type":"Fixed","maxprice":"0.0000","fee_cost":"70.00","stampduty":"False","gst":"True","percentagetotalcost":"False","excessfee":"0.0000","merchantfee":"False","fromage":"0","toage":"0","qtyapply":"False","extradesc":"","extradesc1":"","extradesc2":"","extradesc3":""},{"cattypeid":"6","column1":"MandatoryFees","id":"414","locationid":"5","vehiclesizeid":"4","numofdays":"6","qty":"1","fees":"70.0000","name":"Administration Fee","type":"Fixed","maxprice":"0.0000","fee_cost":"70.00","stampduty":"False","gst":"True","percentagetotalcost":"False","excessfee":"0.0000","merchantfee":"False","fromage":"0","toage":"0","qtyapply":"False","extradesc":"","extradesc1":"","extradesc2":"","extradesc3":""},{"cattypeid":"6","column1":"MandatoryFees","id":"414","locationid":"5","vehiclesizeid":"5","numofdays":"6","qty":"1","fees":"70.0000","name":"Administration Fee","type":"Fixed","maxprice":"0.0000","fee_cost":"70.00","stampduty":"False","gst":"True","percentagetotalcost":"False","excessfee":"0.0000","merchantfee":"False","fromage":"0","toage":"0","qtyapply":"False","extradesc":"","extradesc1":"","extradesc2":"","extradesc3":""},{"cattypeid":"6","column1":"MandatoryFees","id":"414","locationid":"5","vehiclesizeid":"27","numofdays":"6","qty":"1","fees":"70.0000","name":"Administration Fee","type":"Fixed","maxprice":"0.0000","fee_cost":"70.00","stampduty":"False","gst":"True","percentagetotalcost":"False","excessfee":"0.0000","merchantfee":"False","fromage":"0","toage":"0","qtyapply":"False","extradesc":"","extradesc1":"","extradesc2":"","extradesc3":""},{"cattypeid":"6","column1":"MandatoryFees","id":"414","locationid":"5","vehiclesizeid":"30","numofdays":"6","qty":"1","fees":"70.0000","name":"Administration Fee","type":"Fixed","maxprice":"0.0000","fee_cost":"70.00","stampduty":"False","gst":"True","percentagetotalcost":"False","excessfee":"0.0000","merchantfee":"False","fromage":"0","toage":"0","qtyapply":"False","extradesc":"","extradesc1":"","extradesc2":"","extradesc3":""},{"cattypeid":"6","column1":"MandatoryFees","id":"414","locationid":"5","vehiclesizeid":"31","numofdays":"6","qty":"1","fees":"70.0000","name":"Administration Fee","type":"Fixed","maxprice":"0.0000","fee_cost":"70.00","stampduty":"False","gst":"True","percentagetotalcost":"False","excessfee":"0.0000","merchantfee":"False","fromage":"0","toage":"0","qtyapply":"False","extradesc":"","extradesc1":"","extradesc2":"","extradesc3":""},{"cattypeid":"6","column1":"MandatoryFees","id":"414","locationid":"5","vehiclesizeid":"35","numofdays":"6","qty":"1","fees":"70.0000","name":"Administration Fee","type":"Fixed","maxprice":"0.0000","fee_cost":"70.00","stampduty":"False","gst":"True","percentagetotalcost":"False","excessfee":"0.0000","merchantfee":"False","fromage":"0","toage":"0","qtyapply":"False","extradesc":"","extradesc1":"","extradesc2":"","extradesc3":""}];
rcmOptionalFees = [];
rcmInsuranceOptions = [];
rcmKmCharges = [];
rcmTaxInclusive=true;rcmTaxRate=0.100;rcmStateTax=0.000;
rcmErrors = [];
rcmStep2Ready("","","");
```

But I just want only rcmOfficeTimes data

```
[{"id":"10","driverage":"18","defaultage":"False"},{"id":"2","driverage":"19","defaultage":"False"},{"id":"3","driverage":"20","defaultage":"False"},{"id":"4","driverage":"21+","defaultage":"False"}]
```

I need the rcmOfficeTimes dataset from this response data. Anyone can help me

Comment: seems like you are scrapping the entire web page , which is not the proper / legal way to get data from another data source , however your only way is to parse if and get the required data using regex , which will be too expensive in the memory level.

Comment: @hassan `https://apis.rentalcarmanager.com/booking/v3.1/` sounds like a dedicated API URL though. But even if I just try the URL as shown in the initial cURL command above (without any valid API key), the response is `rcmErrors = [{"error":"Invalid Key | Err - No Data connection."}];` - so this thing apparently returns a rather uncommon data format, not sure what exactly the point of that is supposed to be.

Comment: I also post the curl output @CBroe. Can you help me to filter the output

Comment: https://apis.rentalcarmanager.com/booking/v3.1/d3d3LmNhbXBlcm1hbmF1c3RyYWxpYS5jb20=/step2/0/5/25_10_2021/11_00/5/30_10_2021/11_00/2/0/-/-?apikey=d3d3LmNhbXBlcm1hbmF1c3RyYWxpYS5jb20=

Comment: I am not sure what this response is supposed to represent, it looks like it might be _code_ that is expected to get executed now ...? `rcmStep2Ready("","","");` looks like a function call. Doesn't the API documentation (not freely available apparently) say anything about what this format is supposed to be, and whether you can request other formats perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, it says in there, _"The results of API calls are returned as a JavaScript string with variables initialised with JSON data in this format: ..."_ - so you'll either have to find a JS parser, or write something yourself.